# Ignore file both locally an on svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

there is an option in tortoise SVN to add file to ignore list. But I have other issue. For example I have file 1.bat both locally and on SVN. What I wish is for every one who does checkout that file would not be downloaded. And when the user creates his own 1.bat file that will be different from 1.bat on SVN he will not be able to commit or update it. Bottom line, two different files with the same name and no connection between them on commit or update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a file is in the repository, then it cannot be excluded from a download. The only option--which is *not* suitable in your case from the sound of it--is to unversion it without disturbing your local copy (per the official TortoiseSvn docs at [Ignore files which are already versioned](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-unversion.html)).

So far that might be nice to know, but unhelpful. What might help is the following.

What you describe is what I call the **versioned-yet-unversioned-configuration-file-pattern**. (You refer to a batch file, so this might not apply.) The typical scenario is that each user needs to customize a value in a config file that is versioned, yet have one's local changes to that config file ignored by SVN so it does not keep annoying you saying the file is changed and needs to be committed.

To do this, you have to have unique names; no way around that. The trick is in the name--actually *names*. Say you have a config `file my-project.cfg`. I would copy that to `file my-project.cfg.template` and edit it to be a vanilla (uncustomized) file. Then commit this "template" and svn-ignore the original named file (`file my-project.cfg`). You or your colleagues are then free to update the template at any time with changes you want to disseminate, and then each developer has the onus of merging in those changes to his/her actual working file.